# Reading memory card data from application

Tags: android

I am writing one application.When I tap on a button,it has to read data(ring tones) from memory card and dispaly it in the list view I have created.How to read memory card data from the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path of sdcard like:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then give the the foldername and file name
Eg:

```
"/audios/ringtone1.extension"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Using the External Storage" [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Android has an awesome development website. Hope that is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Enviroment Class of Android for such purposes.

Please look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for the same. You will get all the details regarding it there.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

```
if(path != null){

File k = new File(path, "moment.mp3");

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Insert it into the database
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  MainActivity.this,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
  newUri
);
```